# What Matlab packages are good for producing bifurcation diagrams for predator prey systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems, mathematical-biology

So some background, this is my predator-prey system: $\begin{gather*}N_{t+2}=N_t\exp[r(1-\frac{N}{K})]\frac{1-e^{-aP}}{aP}\\ P_{t+1}=N_t[1-\frac{1-e^{-aP}}{aP}]\end{gather*}$. I've tried doing it by hand but ran into problems since I get only an implicit expression when I try to express $P$ and $N$ in terms of the varying parameter $a$. So I figure it is necessary to produce bifurcation diagram through code, any recommendations on how to go about this? What are some packages I could use that can simplify my life a bit? Or do you guys recommend another coding platform like Mathematica to do this?

Answer (score 1):

since there is no answer for your question.

One of the software packages for generating bifurcation diagrams
XPPAUT can deal with continuous and discrete map systems

here is the download link which has some tutorial by the developer

[http://www.math.pitt.edu/~bard/xpp/help/xppexample.html](http://www.math.pitt.edu/%7Ebard/xpp/help/xppexample.html)

Good luck